# Deploy only specific folders in github actions

Tags: github-actions

Can you provide an example of a GitHub workflow that ensures deployment to a server only occurs from specific folders within the repository?

Here is my example, but it only works for the whole repository

```
name: DeployDev14

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Setup key
      - run: set -eu
      - run: mkdir "$HOME/.ssh"
      - run: echo "${{ secrets.KEY }}" > "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"
      - run: chmod 600 "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"
      
      # Deploy
      - run: rsync -e "ssh -p 22 -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --archive --compress --delete . root@##.##.##.##:/home/sites/site.com
```

so I need to deploy only dev folder from site.com repository

Answer (score 0):

Truth to be told, only rsync code is needed here:

```
rsync -e "ssh -p 22 -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --archive --compress --delete . root@##.##.##.##:/home/sites/site.com
```

Particularly `.` which is rsync source directory. Check manual [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

So you have two options:

1. Before running `rsync` go to wanted directory
2. Change `.` (which means current directory) for `<path to dev directory>` (which I assume is `./dev`)